# regex to match and not capture some part of the string

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to capture dates that can be in a string like this

> '30 jan and 6 apr and 12 oct 2022'

I am using python regex module (its the same as re but has 'overlapped' option).I need to have the end result as this list

> ['30 jan 2022', '6 apr 2022', '12 oct 2022']

so far with this expression

```
regex.findall(r'(?:\d\d | \d )(?:jan|feb|mar|ap|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)(?:.*)20(?:\d\d)', d, overlapped=True)
```

I am getting

> ['30 jan and 6 apr and 12 oct 2022', ' 6 apr and 12 oct 2022', '12 oct 2022']

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a list comprehension and 2 capture groups:

```
\b(\d+ (?:jan|feb|mar|ap|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))(?=.*\b(20\d\d))\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MzA1iq/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RRQD8V).

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(\d+ (?:jan|feb|mar|ap|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))(?=.*\b(20\d\d))\b"
s = r"30 jan and 6 apr and 12 oct 2022"

res = [' '.join(s) for s in re.findall(pattern, s)]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['30 jan 2022', '6 ap 2022', '12 oct 2022']
```

Note that `(?:.*)` and `(?:\d\d)` do not need the non capture group, as the group by itself has no purpose in the pattern.

Comment: It works thank you!
I was just wandering (and maybe you also know this) if there is a way to just leave out the `.*` part after month?
In case of `30 jan and 6 apr and 12 oct 2022` when it matches `jan` or `apr` to  just ignore everything until 2022.

Comment: @Sev You can not leave out the `.*` in the patter, as the lookahead is asserting a year which is not directly after any of the month names. The `.*` in the pattern does not actually match anything, it is part of the non consuming lookahead, which has a capture group by it self that does take part in the final output.